One person <as'll vs who will>


I know one person as'll eat it.
I know one person who will eat it.


The first one is from a grammar book,  demonstrating the use of "as",  while the second one is with the pattern that i am familiar with.
Do they mean the same thing, and the only difference is the second one is the more formal, common one?

Yes, they mean the same, but the first is nonstandard speech. Does the book not explain this?

@KateBunting   The book mentions "as"  can sometimes serves as a relative word in a side note,  without further explanation or comparison with other relative words.

The use of as such as you show in in your sentence (1) I know one person as'll (as will) eat it is non-standard or regional or rural dialect English. It's shown in Biber et al 1999 (is that where you saw it?) but not marked as non-standard, however it is characterized as vulgar or dialectal by Jespersen 1925 among others.

@MichaelHarvey  Not this book.  The book I'm reading is by non native speakers. Are there any subtle differences? For example, can it be understood that "as" means he is just the kind of person who will eat this kind of thing, while with "who" it means he will really come here and eat this thing"?

ForOU - there are no differences, subtle or unsubtle, in meaning between (1) one person as'll eat and (2) one person who'll eat. The only difference is that in (1) 'as' is an archaic or rural/uneducated/regional dialect equivalent or replacement for 'who'.

@ishtar - only in references.

As will will be understood by Americans as slang. But as'll will take three reads to decipher. So, I don't use anything to slow the reader.

@YosefBaskin - in my experience, some of the best writers are those who make me do some work.

Turning the comments into an answer: The first example is a very limited regional usage, and the second is standard. There's no difference in meaning, but since you don't belong to that region or group, you should choose the second.
